# Assign a value to element in list of list that assigning to a row of values

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I created a list of lists like this

```
In [1]: list_of_list = [ [0] * 4]* 4
In [2]: list_of_list

Out[2]: [[0, 0, 0, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0], 
         [0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0],]
```

And when I assign a value to the element in this `list_of_list` it assigns it to a column of elements.

```
In [3]: list_of_list[2][3]
Out[3]: 0

In [4]: list_of_list[2][3] = 1

In [5]: list_of_list
Out[5]: [[0, 0, 0, 1], 
         [0, 0, 0, 1], 
         [0, 0, 0, 1], 
         [0, 0, 0, 1],]
```

Why python behave like this ?

Thank you.

Comment: use the link at the top of your question to find the duplicate

Comment: I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation:

```
[0] * 4
```

Creates a list of four zeros. This is fine, each is copied by value in python since numbers less than 255 are effectively treated as "primitives".

However,

```
list_of_list = [[0, 0, 0, 0]]* 4
```

Copies the list *by reference*. Anything that happens to one of these lists happens to all of them.